# SetTimeout() for NFC Tag Type NfcV Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, timeout, nfc

I have a device for which one of its commands takes about 80ms to perform its operation before sending a response via NFC. This triggers the time out and returns an exception.

Android Studio is throwing me an `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.` exception.

the NFC-V API does not have any `setTimeout()` method as some other NFC technologies.
Anyone knows any way I can extend the time period for the time out?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to catch the exception and continue anyhow. I could do that, as I was sending a write command, where I do not need a response. This is not ideal, because you will not able to find "real" errors.

If you need the response, e.g. your command is a read command, then ignoring the exception may not work

Answer (score 0):

The Hard coded timeout seem to be 100ms from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/nfc/tags/rw_i93.cc

And the answer is probably you cannot change it as

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36974890 was closed as "Won't Fix (Obsolete)"